# Ambiguous imported type 'PrintJob':'android.print.printjob' or 'android.printservice.printjob' error for android printing app

Tags: java, android, ambiguous

My name is Ibrahim. I came to America 8 years ago. I have no accent, my voice is very normal. I have developed an interest for computer repair and development ever since I  was 12. I first started coding my freshman year of high school last year. I am developing an app for people who use bluetooth printers.
I got this error when I finished the MainActivity.java page.
Here is my mainactivity.java code:

```
    package com.mycompany.printer;

    import android.app.*;
    import android.os.*;
    import android.view.*;
    import android.widget.*;
    import android.bluetooth.*;
    import android.print.*;
    import android.printservice.*;
    import android.view.View.*;
    import android.print.PrintJob.*;
    import java.awt.print.*;
    import java.awt.*;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity
    {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            Button connect= (Button) findViewById(R.id.connect);
            connect.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View p1)
                    {
                 BluetoothAdapter ba = (BluetoothAdapter) getSystemService(BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
                   ba.enable();
                   ba.startDiscovery();


                    }




            });
            Button disconnect=(Button) findViewById(R.id.disconnect);
            disconnect.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View p1)
                    {
                    BluetoothAdapter ba = (BluetoothAdapter) getSystemService(BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
                    ba.cancelDiscovery();
                    ba.disable();
                    }



            });
            Button print = (Button) findViewById(R.id.print);
            print.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View p1)
                    {
   PrintJob pj = (PrintJob) getSystemService(PRINT_SERVICE);
pj.start();
                    }


            });
        }
    }
```

Here is my main.xml code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Connect to printer"
            android:id="@+id/connect"/>
        <button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="disconnect from printer"
            android:id="@+id/disconnect"
            />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Print"
        android:id="@+id/print"/>
    </LinearLayout>


and finally, here is my R.java code:

/* AUTO-GENERATED FILE.  DO NOT MODIFY.
 *
 * This class was automatically generated by the
 * aapt tool from the resource data it found.  It
 * should not be modified by hand.
 */

package com.mycompany.printer;

public final class R {
    public static final class attr {
    }
    public static final class drawable {
        public static final int ic_launcher=0x7f020000;
    }
    public static final class id {
        public static final int connect=0x7f060000;
        public static final int disconnect=0x7f060001;
        public static final int print=0x7f060002;
    }
    public static final class layout {
        public static final int main=0x7f030000;
    }
    public static final class string {
        public static final int app_name=0x7f040001;
        public static final int hello=0x7f040000;
    }
    public static final class style {
        public static final int AppTheme=0x7f050000;
    }
}
```

At this part of the app:

```
 Button print = (Button) findViewById(R.id.print);
                    print.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View p1)
                            {
           PrintJob pj = (PrintJob) getSystemService(PRINT_SERVICE);
        pj.start();
                            }
```

I get error Ambiguous imported type 'PrintJob':'android.print.printjob' or 'android.printservice.printjob'

Comment: Welcome to SO Ibrahim. You should put your intro on your profile page and not the question.

Answer (score 1):

The error is saying that it doesn't know whether to use the class android.print.PrintJob or android.printservice.PrintJob. 
In this case you'll want to use android.printservice.PrintJob because this class has the start() method that you're looking to call: `pj.start();`.
Either

1. Replace your import of android.print.PrintJob with android.printservice.PrintJob. Or
2. Remove the import and then state the fully qualified name in the call:

   android.printservice.PrintJob pj = (android.printservice.PrintJob) getSystemService(PRINT_SERVICE);

Answer (score -1):

PrintJob pj = (PrintJob) getSystemService(PRINT_SERVICE);

android.printservice.PrintManager pm = (PrintManager)getSystemService(PRINT_SERVICE);
pm.print(String, PrintDocumentAdaper, attr);

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question will be much better.

Comment: Thank you but I dropped the project.